# View height returns 0 when moving to another fragment and then navigate back android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-view, android-xml

I have two `fragments`. In `fragment A` there is a `RecyclerView`, when I click on the element of which I get to another `fragment B`. In `fragment A` I have a MaterialToolbar which can have different heights, so in `onViewCreated()` I call `materialToolbar.height` to get its height. When I open `fragment A` everything works fine, however when I click on an element in the `RecyclerView`, I get to `fragment B`, in which on pressing the back button I will go back to the `fragment A` and the height of my `materialToolbar` will already be 0. Why does it return 0? And how can I make it return the value I need?

Comment: Check this, i think that for your particular problem the best option is to use.
View.getMeasuredHeigth()
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591784/views-getwidth-and-getheight-returns-0

Comment: Can you please share some code for us to understand. Especially where you set toolbar height in fragment A.

Answer (score 0):

There's an observer which listens to view-heirarchy of any given view.

```
toolbar.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
        override fun onGlobalLayout() {
            binding.mbSelect.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
            val height = materialToolbar.height
        }
    })
```

Try this above code in you fragment A, you will get the actual height toolbar